# How to apply hover effect to image when hovering over a button placed on top of that image?

Tags: css, hover, parent-child

I have applied a hover effect to an image and want to keep this hover effect when hovering over a button placed on top of that image. I know questions around these types of parent/child issues have been asked before but these answers were not extensive enough to help me resolve this particular issue on my own. A CSS only solution would be nice but I guess it requires some JS to work around it.

Here is the JSfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/stijn777/k8dbfs3r/3/

As you can see in the HTML below I want the hover effect on the image class to also be applied when hovering over the button inside the picture class.

```
<div class="picture">
<a class="image" href="./profile-picture.html">
<img alt="" src="http://www.liverpoolblogg.no/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/Daniel-Sturridge1.jpg">
</a>
<input class="image btn  btn-6 btn-6d" a href="www.test.com" type="button" value=" ADD " />
<div class="player">
<a href="./profile.html">Name</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I used the following CSS for the image and the button on top of the image.

```
.image:after {
content:'\A';
position:absolute;
width:55%; height: 70%;
top:0; left:0;
background:rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
opacity:0;
border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}

.image {
width: 100%;
}

.image:hover:after {
opacity:1;
}

.picture:hover input {
display: block;
}

.picture .player {
position:absolute;
margin-top: -40px;
background-color: white;
opacity: 0.7;
width: 55%;
height: 40px;
padding-top: 8px;
text-align: center;
}

.player a {
color: #000000;
font-family: sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
text-decoration: none;
}


.picture input {
position:absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
margin-top: 10px;
width: 55%;
}
```

Hope someone can help me out,

Stijn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `.image:hover:after` rule to `.picture:hover .image:after`. :hover applies to whatever your mouse is over, as well as its parent element(s), but the button and image are siblings. changing the hover to be detected on their mutual parent div (.picture) causes the hover to be correctly detected

`.picture:hover .image:after {
opacity:1;
}`

http://jsfiddle.net/5n7gj8uc/

Comment: Wow, thats a lot easier than I thought it would be! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could activate the hover effect using the parent div, like so:

```
.picture:hover > .image:after {
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k8dbfs3r/5/